# What is the correct separable Schrödinger equation in spherical coordinates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

What is the correct separable [Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Hydrogen_atom) in spherical coordinates?

Some articles use this formula:
$$ \Psi(r,\theta,\phi) = R(r)\cdot\Theta(\theta)\cdot \Phi(\phi),  $$
and some of them use:
$$ \Psi(r,\theta,\phi) =\frac{R(r)\cdot \Theta(\theta)\cdot \Phi(\phi) }{r}.  $$

So which is true?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both formulas are correct. And it is essentially a matter of taste
which one you prefer:

- If you use the separation approach
  $$\Psi(r,\theta,\phi) = R(r) \cdot \Theta(\theta) \cdot \Phi(\phi)$$
  then you get the radial differential equation
  $${\frac {1}{r^{2}}}{\frac {d}{dr}}\left(r^{2}{\frac {dR}{dr}}\right)-{\frac {\ell (\ell +1)}{r^{2}}R+{\frac {2m}{\hbar ^{2}}}\left[E-V(r)\right]R=0}$$
  (like in [Wikipedia - Particle in a spherically symmetric potential - Derivation of the radial equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_spherically_symmetric_potential#Derivation_of_the_radial_equation))
  with the normalization condition
  $$\int_0^\infty dr\ r^2 |R(r)|^2=1.$$
- If you use the separation approach
  $$\Psi(r,\theta,\phi) = \frac{u(r)}{r} \cdot \Theta(\theta) \cdot \Phi(\phi)$$
  then you get the radial differential equation
  $$\frac {d^2u}{dr^2}-{\frac {\ell (\ell +1)}{r^{2}}u+{\frac {2m}{\hbar ^{2}}}\left[E-V(r)\right]u=0}$$
  with the normalization condition
  $$\int_0^\infty dr\ |u(r)|^2=1.$$

At the end you get the same solutions $\Psi(r,\theta,\phi)$ in both cases
because $R(r)=\frac{u(r)}{r}$.
However, the approach with $u(r)$ leads to simpler math
and has more similarity with a 1-dimensional Schrödinger equation.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, then the second one is used for (I guess) when we solve the radial part. We have to put $R(r)=u(r)/r$, so maybe in second one they have written $R(r)/r$ instead of $R(r)$ is because they put directly $R(r)/r$. I am not sure though.

Comment: Firstly I need to find radial, angular and azimuthal parts, then solve them.

Comment: Generally the angular and azimuthal parts are solved first and then radial but u can do either.

Comment: You will get a different equation because you have to derive $R/r$ twice. you can take a look at a laplacian equation.

Comment: U can solve radial eqn using the following method,
Near r=0 the differential equation for radial part is d^2u/dx^2=l(l+1)/r^2, now let u=r^s,then putting the value of u in the diiferential eqn, we gets(s-1)=l(l+1), therefore s=l+1, and the solution is u(r)=r^(l+1) or R(r)=r^l